# Display titles which are missing association values partially or completely

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having problem writing SQL query for the following scenario. I need someone's help to write the query.

I have the following tables 7 tables:

1) Titles

```
ID    Title                                                        Author         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software   Charles Petzold
2     Paths, Dangers, Strategies                              Nick Bostrom
3     The Smart Girl's Guide to Privacy                       Violet Blue
4     Introduction to Algorithms                              Thomas H. Cormen
5     Machine Learning in Action                              Peter Harrington
...
```

2) Themes

```
ID         Name
------------------------------------------
1          Science Fiction
2          Biography
3          Painting
...
```

3)   Subjects

```
ID           Name
-----------------------------------
1            Science 
2            Technology
3            Music
4            Geography
...
```

4)  Grades

```
ID            Name
------------------------------------
1             Grade 1
2             Grade 2
3             Grade 3
4             Grade 4
5             Grade 5
...
```

5) TitleThemeAssociation

```
TitleID         ThemeID
------------------------------------------
1               1
1               3
4               2
4               3
...
```

6) TitleSubjectAssociaton

```
TitleID          SubjectID
---------------------------------
1                1
1                3
2                1
2                3 
4                1
4                2  
...
```

7) TitleGradeAssociaton

```
TitleID              GradeID
1                    1
1                    2
1                    3
2                    1
2                    2
...
```

I need to write a query to display only titles which are missing any of three values (Themes, Subjects and Grades) or not assigned values completely. I should not display the title if all three values (Themes, Subjects, Grades) are assigned. In the above data set since **TitleID 1** has all three values it should not be present in the list. **TitleID 2** has only Subjects and Grades assigned but not Themes so it should be displayed in the output. While listing the titles if a title has multiple values then they should be contacted with comma (,) separator.

So the final output of the above data set should be as below:

Output:

```
Title ID      Title                      Theme        Subject           Grade
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2      Paths, Dangers, Strategies          -          Science, Music    Grade 1, Grade 2
3      The Smart Girl's Guide to Privacy   -           -                   -
4      Introduction to Algorithms         Biography, Painting    Science, Technology    -
5      Machine Learning in Action          -              -              -
```

Comment: `I am having problem writing SQL query` - how can we help you fix your query if you haven't posted it? :)

Comment: There are a couple of different ways you could do this.  One method is to use an [outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx).  Outer joins can be used to find records that appear in one table, but not another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are essentially two questions you're asking.  The first being how to filter when either a `Theme`, `Subject` or `Grade` is missing.  And the other is asking how to concat these items into a comma separated list.

The following query should be what you're looking for:

```
Select  Distinct
        T.Id As [Title ID],
        T.Title,
        H.Theme,
        S.Subject,
        G.Grade
From    Titles  T
Outer Apply
(
    Select  Stuff(( Select ', ' + Name 
                    From    Themes                  H
                    Join    TitleThemeAssociation   TH  On  H.Id = TH.ThemeId
                    Where   TH.TitleId = T.Id 
                    For Xml Path('')), 1, 2, '') As Theme
    From    Themes
) H
Outer Apply
(
    Select  Stuff(( Select ', ' + Name 
                    From    Subjects                S
                    Join    TitleSubjectAssociaton  TS  On  S.Id = TS.SubjectId
                    Where   TS.TitleId = T.Id 
                    For Xml Path('')), 1, 2, '') As Subject
    From    Subjects
) S
Outer Apply
(
    Select  Stuff(( Select ', ' + Name 
                    From    Grades                  G
                    Join    TitleGradeAssociaton    TG  On  G.Id = TG.GradeId
                    Where   TG.TitleId = T.Id 
                    For Xml Path('')), 1, 2, '') As Grade
    From    Grades
) G
Where   H.Theme Is Null
Or      S.Subject Is Null
Or      G.Grade Is Null
```

Comment: I want to get RowNumber as well but when I add the field it giving odd output. How can I achieve the result? Can you please look into my problem. 
Select  Distinct
  ROW_NUMBER() over 
    (
     ORDER BY [id] ASC
    ) as RowNumber
        ,T.Id As [Title ID],
        T.Title,
        H.Theme,
        S.Subject,
        G.Grade
From    Titles  T ........

Answer (score 1):

Hope this Helps.

```
;WITH cte_Titles (ID,Title,Author)   AS     
(
SELECT 1,'The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software','Charles Petzold' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Paths, Dangers, Strategies','Nick Bostrom' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'The Smart Girls Guide to Privacy','Violet Blue' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Introduction to Algorithms','Thomas H. Cormen' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'Machine Learning in Action','Peter Harrington'
),cte_Themes(ID,Name) AS
(
SELECT 1,'Science Fiction' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Biography' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Painting'
),cte_Subjects(ID,Name) AS
(
SELECT 1,'Science' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Technology' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Music' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Geography'
),cte_Grades(ID,Name) AS
(
SELECT 1,'Grade 1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Grade 2' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Grade 3' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Grade 4' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'Grade 5'
),cte_TitleThemeAssociation(TitleID,ThemeID) AS
(
SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,3
),cte_TitleSubjectAssociaton(TitleID,SubjectID) AS
(
SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2
),cte_TitleGradeAssociaton(TitleID,GradeID) AS
(
SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2
)
,cte_ResultSet AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID AS TitleID,
    t.Title,
    th.NAME AS Theme,
    s.NAME AS Subject,
    g.NAME AS Grade
FROM cte_Titles t
LEFT JOIN cte_TitleThemeAssociation tta
    ON t.ID = tta.TitleID
LEFT JOIN cte_Themes th
    ON tta.ThemeID = th.ID
LEFT JOIN cte_TitleSubjectAssociaton tsa
    ON tsa.TitleID = t.ID
LEFT JOIN cte_Subjects s
    ON tsa.SubjectID = s.ID
LEFT JOIN cte_TitleGradeAssociaton tga
    ON tga.TitleID = t.ID
LEFT JOIN cte_Grades g
    ON g.ID = tga.GradeID
)
SELECT DISTINCT Title
                , STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + SUB.Theme AS [text()]
                        FROM cte_ResultSet SUB
                        WHERE SUB.TitleID = CAT.TitleID
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '' ) AS Theme
                , STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + SUB.Subject AS [text()]
                        FROM cte_ResultSet SUB
                        WHERE SUB.TitleID = CAT.TitleID
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '' ) AS Subject
                , STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + SUB.Grade AS [text()]
                        FROM cte_ResultSet SUB
                        WHERE SUB.TitleID = CAT.TitleID
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '' ) AS Grade
FROM cte_ResultSet CAT
```